# How to get element's index by xpath?

Tags: xpath, indexing, element

I've next structure :

```
<div id='list'>
   <div class='column'>aaa</div>
   <div class='column'>bbb</div>
   ...
   <div class='column'>jjj</div>
</div>
```

I was wonder if there is a ways to use XPath, and to write some query were I can get the index of the requested element within the "list" element.

I mean that I'll ask for location of `class='column'` where the text value is `aaa` and I'll get `0` or `1`...

Thanks

Comment: See a good and simple tutorial like http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp.

Answer (score 8):

You could just count the div elements preceding the element you're looking for:

```
count(div[@id = 'list']/div[@id = 'myid']/preceding-sibling::div)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `count` the preceding siblings:

```
count(//div[@id="list"]/div[@id="3"]/preceding-sibling::*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Selenium way to evaluate the position:

```
 int position = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='column' and text()='jjj']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='column']")).size() + 1;
System.out.println(position);
```

Comment: Didn't get it... The size will always return the total number of elements matching the xpath, and then add one to it. How does it allow fetching the position of that element in the dom.

Comment: By "doesn't work" I mean you can't know if you found the first column (which doesn't have preceding siblings), or didn't find a column with given text at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can count how many "preceding-siblings" that are also of class 'column', by using this xpath:

```
//div[@class='column' and text()='jjj']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='column']
```