# How do I return the index of a node from XML stored in an Oracle XML table?

Tags: xml, oracle, indexing, position

I've stored XML in an Oracle XML table and I want to query the table and return the index value for a node in a group of four that has a specific attribute value.  In the example below, I want to return the index of the answer with value @correct="True".

```
<answerset set_id="4" >
    <answer correct="True" ><![CDATA[diamond]]></answer>
    <answer correct="False" ><![CDATA[carbon]]></answer>
    <answer correct="False" ><![CDATA[quartz]]></answer>
    <answer correct="False" ><![CDATA[rubinite]]></answer>
</answerset>
```

I can easily query the table and get the node with the @correct value of "True":

```
SELECT item_name, answer
FROM TEST_XML, xmltable('/testitem' passing test_xml.sys_nc_rowinfo$
columns
item_name VARCHAR2(100) path '@item_name',
--distracter VARCHAR2(1000) path 
answer VARCHAR2(1000) path 
'/testitem/answersets/answerset[last()]/answer[@correct="True"]') Item;


ITEM_NAME      ANSWER
MINERAL        DIAMOND
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get XPath functions or other functions to work to return the index or position of the answer, which -- in this case -- would be "1".

This looks like a close answer but I haven't figured out how to use the functionality in the context of an Oracle XML query:

count(answerset[last()]/answer[@correct = 'True']/preceding-sibling::answer)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16519582/3757890

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression does not match the XML document. Anyway, I assume you are looking for `FOR ORDINALITY`:

```
SELECT item_name, answer, POSITION
FROM TEST_XML, 
    xmltable('/testitem' passing test_xml.sys_nc_rowinfo$ columns
    POSITION FOR ORDINALITY,
    item_name VARCHAR2(100) path '@item_name',
    distracter VARCHAR2(1000) path '/testitem/answersets/answerset[last()]/answer[@correct="True"]') Item;
```